# Prevent Chrome browser from converting position property to inset

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-position

I have been battling with this issue for days now and I'm not sure why chrome browser converts CSS position properties (Top, Right, Bottom, Left) to inset property (which is not generally supported by most browsers).

I worked on an editor in which when you edit your element in chrome it converts the CSS position properties to inset like below

[image]

But when you view element created on chrome with the inset property on other browsers. The inset property is either removed or strikeout with the warning `Unsupported Property Name` (See below image)

[image]

But if I use browsers like Brave or Safari to build my page using the editor, the CSS position properties remain Top, Right, Bottom, Left. (see below image)

[image]

My question is how can I work around this since a wide number of people including me uses chrome and the inset property only works on chrome and android devices, iOS not supported.

Any help in the right direction will be really appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**
Below is my code, which works exactly like this on Brave, Safari but chrome converts to inset.

[image]

**UPDATE 2**
The editor Saves the HTML and the HTML is used across all browsers. When the page is edited using chrome and the CSS position property is updated to `Inset` ... `Inset` is then used across all browsers (and it's not supported by those browsers (safari and brave) ) ... but if I edit my page from Brave browser or safari and save the editor, `top, right, bottom, left` CSS position property is used and the page renders as expected on all browser

**MY SOLUTION**
Below is how I solve the issue in jQuery. For AngularJS, please see answer by @user10245459. My Solution assumes you have access to the entire HTML because in my case whenever I save the editor, the HTML is for the page is available to me, so I created a function to look through the HTML code and update the `inset` style before putting the HTML code in a file

```
/**
 * A Very stressful/Painful hack for chrome converting Positing
 * Properties to inset, causing text and heading to stack over each other
 * in a corner on iOS mobile, IE/EDGE, Samsung Internet
 */
function updateInsetProperty( HTMLstring ) {
    var _allStyles =  HTMLstring.match(/style="([^"]*)"/g);
    var _insetBank = [];
    $.each(_allStyles, function(i, style){
        var onlyStyleInsetProperty = style.replace(/&quot;/, '').match(/inset:\s?([A-Za-z\s0-9\.\-]+)?/i);
        if( onlyStyleInsetProperty != null ) {
            var _splitInset = onlyStyleInsetProperty[1].split(' ');
            var _insetReplacement = `top:${_splitInset[0]}; right:${_splitInset[1]}; bottom:${_splitInset[2]}; left:${_splitInset[3]}`;
            var formattedStyle = HTMLstring.replace(onlyStyleInsetProperty[0], _insetReplacement);
            HTMLstring = formattedStyle;
        }
    });

    return HTMLstring;
}
```

Then you can call the function like this.

```
var htmlCodeForMobile = updateInsetProperty(htmlTmp_mbl);
var htmlCodeForDesktop = updateInsetProperty(htmlTmp_dsk);

 // Note: htmlTmp_mbl is the HTML code for mobile from 
 // the editor (in my case) or HTML from your source 
 // while htmlTmp_dsk is the HTML for desktop.
```

Comment: this is my code https://imgur.com/WxAnRb7 and it is rendered exactly as it is on safari and brave but chrome converts it to inset

Comment: You're voting to close the question ... @melancia ... I have no inset anywhere in my code but was added as you can see here imgur.com/WxAnRb7. So I'm not sure why the question is Voted down and voted to close

Comment: The editor saves the HTML property (which is inline CSS styling) because it was edited from a chrome browser... This is why my question was how to prevent chrome from behaving this way.

Comment: I didn't set any shorthand for the property, I see no reason why the browser should assume that or change to shorthand for me... Brave and Chrome are running on Chromium but Brave didn't assume or change the property to shorthand ... why should Chrome behave that way and assume? if the property is widely supported, that wouldn't be an issue but Samsung Internet, iOS mobile, Safari Desktop, IE don't support this. Users on android get the layout correctly but iOS users get a really distorted layout just because of this issue

Comment: Tssk!!! With `filter`, I'm the one adding the property filter .. so I'd always use vendor prefix whenever I use such property... but in this case, I didn't use `inset` property ... why should it be added for me? This is why I asked this question. I will stop replying at this point. Thank you for your time

Comment: Really don't understand why chrome behave like this, does anyone know the reason? Thanks for the question saved me!

Answer (score 2):

Just had a similar issue. Adding "!important" into any one of position properties will prevent converting to inset (strangely enough).

In my case, for example, from this:

```
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

To this:

```
top: 0 !important;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue when i use angular ngStyle
[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQu0V.png

```
<div class="content" [ngStyle]="getStyleByKeys(content.propList, styleKeys)"></dvi>
```

I found a workaround, just for your reference. Hope it helps:
[2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNqVd.png

```
<div class="content" [attr.style]="(getStyleString(getStyleByKeys(content.propList, styleKeys))) | safeStyle"></div>
```

```
import { pick } from 'lodash';

getStyleByKeys(props, keys): any {
    let res = {};

    if ( !props ) { return {}; }
    if ( keys ) { res = pick(props, keys); }
    return res;
}
getStyleString(o: any): any {
    return Object.keys(o).reduce((style, i) => {
        style += `${i}: ${o[i]}; `;
        return style;
    }, '');
}
``
```

Comment: I did something similar to fix my issue as well ... I will update my question with the JS code I used

Comment: Updated my question with the jQuery Solution I used @10Rep. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can also add width: 100%, height: 100% to the element, to keep the position.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add my two cents. In my particular situation, this css transformation converting position properties to inset was being done by my bundler, esbuild, as part of its **minify** routine.

Therefore, I would recommend as a debugging measure, try turning off the minify feature of your bundler to see if the transformation to `inset` stops.

I tried doing that, and the transformation stops. Therefore, I believe it's not Chrome doing the transformation, it's rather your minifier.

Comment: My setup doesn't use any bundler as my use case was written in jQuery. On Chromium browsers the position properties are converted to `inset` and on other browsers, it wasn't transformed.

So yeah, it's a chrome problem but hey maybe your setup has a way to strictly telling chrome not to transform

Comment: Kolawole Emmanuel Izzy, that's fascinating. I'll have to keep in mind then that Chrome has the possibility of transforming styles. Thanks for this note.